# Display .phtml content into static block

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I would like to add the content of a phtml file into a static block on Magento 1.9.2.2.

phtml file is in:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/PBS_Freeship/soglia.phtml
```

with a very basic code I will edit later:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

static block's ID is `freeshipcart`, with the following content:

```
<p><a href="spedizioni-e-consegne/"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ShippingPerCarrello.jpg"}}" /></a></p>
<p>text</p>
<p>{{block type="freeshipcart/soglia" name="soglia" template="Pbs_Freeship/soglia.phtml"}}</p>
```

"freeshipcart/soglia" is allowed in Blocks Permission.

Can't figure it out why this static block shows all but "hello" from the phtml file. Am I missing something?

Comment: The block `freeshipcart/soglia` exists? Did you try `core/template`instead?

Comment: It worked with core/template, I misunderstood the block type values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these code in content of static block you created.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="myCustom" template="cms/my_custom.phtml"}}
```

also add your File in this Location `cms/my_custom.phtml`

Comment: Do you mean /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/my_custom.phtml?

Comment: yes i meant that only..

Comment: It worked, then I added core/template to my block and static block showed also my phtml file. Thanks!